# Size of Matlab buttons and Matlab code changes after first run on Windows 10

Tags: matlab, windows-10

I am running Matlab on Windows 10. On Windows 10, I have the option, "Size of Text, Apps and other items" set to 175%. When I open Matlab, all the buttons and Matlab code appear larger as expected for 175%. However, when I run a matlab code, the size of the matlab icons and the matlab buttons becomes much smaller (roughly by about 75%). I think it is not detecting that my windows setting after the first run. Is there any way I can fix this. As my laptop screen is rather small, I need to use 175% zoom to be able to see the icons clearly.

Comment: You should call Mathworks tech support with this.